# Weird apache behavior when trying to display urls without html extension

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, seo

I have a url that is easily accessible when you request it as:

```
    http://example.com/2005/01/example.html

    or

    http://example.com/2005/01/example
```

(I actually don't know why it works without the extension. Instead, it should return the usual 404 error.)

However, when I try to access the following url:

```
    http://example.com/2005/01/example/
    (note the trailing slash)
```

I get a 404 Not found error but with the requested url printed as:

```
    http://example.com/2005/01/example.html/
```

So, it seems the ".html" part was automatically added by apache.

My question is: how do I disable this behavior? I need to do it because I want add mod_rewrite rules to hide the html extension, so that I can access that url as:

```
    http://example.com/2005/01/example/
```

My apache is 2.2.9 on Ubuntu 8.10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) could cause this behavior. Try to disable it:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: That was exactly the cause, the behavior dissappeared upon adding that configuration (I googled for a bit but couldn't find anything similar to my issue) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Is example.html an actual file that lies in the directory path 2005/01? It seems like mod_rewrite is already active. If you use a blog or content management system on your server, then it probably does stuff to your url's already.

Comment: Yes example.html is an actual file. I'm actually trying out Jekyll which is a static file generator, so I had no rewrite rules, but now is time to add them. Thanks.